# Matrix inversion via Levi-Civita symbols

Tags: matrices, inverse, tensors

Using Cramer's formula for the inverse of a matrix $M_{ij}$, is it possible to express the entries $(M^{-1})_{ij}$ in terms of the entries $M_{ij}$ using the Levi-Civita symbol and Kronecker deltas? It seems like this should be possible but I can't find such a formula written out anywhere, and if the formula is known I'd rather not have to work out all the algebra by hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed such a formula. You would think it would be widely known, but in fact the only place I've seen it is in the [Penrose Graphical Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation#Determinant) in Penrose's "Road to Reality".

The formula for the determinant (in $n$ dimensions) is:
$$\det(M)=\tfrac 1{n!}\varepsilon^{i_1i_2\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{j_1j_2\dots j_n}M^{j_1}_{\quad i_1}M^{j_2}_{\quad i_2}\dots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n}$$
For the adjugate:
$$\mathrm{adj}(M)^i_{\; j}=\tfrac 1{(n-1)!}\;\varepsilon^{ii_2\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{jj_2\dots j_n}M^{j_2}_{\quad i_2}\dots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n}$$
and the inverse is the quotient of these two:
$$(M^{-1})^i_{\; j}=\frac{\mathrm{adj}(M)^i_{\; j}}{\det(M)}$$
(If you don't know how "up and down" indices work, just imagine that they are all down.)

If you think about these for a little bit you should be able to see why they replicate Cramer's formula.

---

**What to do when both indices of $M$ are down**

Note that $\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}$ isn't actually a tensor. If it was then considering the change-of-basis matrix $A$ would give us that
$$A^{i_1}_{\quad j_1}\dots A^{i_n}_{\quad j_n} \varepsilon^{j_1\dots j_n}=\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}$$
for every matrix $A$. But in fact we have
$$A^{i_1}_{\quad j_1}\dots A^{i_n}_{\quad j_n} \varepsilon^{j_1\dots j_n}=\det(A)\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}.$$
So $\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}$ doesn't have the right transformation properties to be a tensor*. Luckily $\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}$ fails to be a tensor in the opposite way:
$$(A^{-1})^{j_1}_{\quad i_1}\dots (A^{-1})^{j_n}_{\quad i_n} \varepsilon_{j_1\dots j_n}=\det(A^{-1})\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}$$
and so the product $\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{j_1\dots j_n}$ really is a tensor. (Another way to see this is to note that
$$\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{j_1\dots j_n}=\delta^{[i_1}_{\quad j_1}\dots\delta^{i_n]}_{\quad j_n},$$
where the RHS is clearly a tensor. We could use this expression in the above formulae for $\det$ and $\mathrm{adj}$ if we preferred to not use non-tensors.)

When we wish to invert a matrix with two indices down we begin to worry that we have a problem:
$$\det(M)=\tfrac 1{n!}\varepsilon^{i_1\dots i_n}\varepsilon^{j_1\dots j_n}M_{j_1 i_1}\dots M_{j_n i_n}$$
ain't a scalar and
$$\mathrm{adj}(M)^{ij}=\tfrac 1{(n-1)!}\;\varepsilon^{ii_2\dots i_n}\varepsilon^{jj_2\dots j_n}M_{j_2 i_2}\dots M_{j_n i_n}$$
ain't a tensor. They transform as:
$$\det(M)\mapsto\det(A)^2\det(M)$$
and
$$\mathrm{adj}(M)\mapsto\det(A)^2\mathrm{adj}(M)$$
But of course it all works out alright in the end; taking their quotient cancels the $\det(A)^2$s and so the inverse really is a tensor.

*Although note that sometimes our space is equipped with a canonical volume form, and then we can demand that our bases are such that that voulume form is the canonical one for that basis. Then our change-of-basis matrices are restricted to $SL$ and all is good.

Comment: I like up and down indices. I would think this would be widely known, since writing inverses of, e.g., metric tensors, is an important thing in (pseudo)-Riemannian geometry! The reason I wrote the indices down was because I was in particular looking at writing a formula for the contravariant metric tensor, given the covariant metric tensor.

Comment: @Blake See my edit to the post.