# Determinant derivative in index notation

Tags: derivatives, tensors, index-notation

I'm new to index notation and i'm trying to prove the identity $$\frac{d}{dt}\det(A(t))=\det(A)\operatorname{tr} \left(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}\right) $$ for the special case when $A$ is an invertible second order tensor, using just index notation in the following fashion:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\det(A(t)) & =\frac{d}{dt}(\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{i1}A_{j2}A_{k3}) \\[10pt] & =\varepsilon_{ijk} \left(\frac{d}{dt}(A_{i1})A_{j2}A_{k3}+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{j2})A_{i1}A_{k3}+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{k3})A_{i1}A_{j2})\right) \\[10pt]
& =\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{r1}A_{j2}A_{k3} \left( A^{-1}_{1r}\frac{A_{i1}}{dt} + A^{-1}_{2r} \frac{A_{j2}}{dt}+A^{-1}_{3r}\frac{A_{k3}}{dt} \right)
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon$ is the permutation symbol. This is as far as I can get and it frustrates me because if I just switch the index "$r$" to "$i$" then the proof is done. Have I missed something obvious or made some error? I don't know how to proceed from here.

Best regards
Bengt

Comment: Hint: $\det(A)A^{-1}$ is the adjugate matrix of $A$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Jacobi's_formula

Comment: I will use the theory you propose when proving this identity for a invertible tensor of order n. The present case is mostly so that I can practice using index notation, do you have any hints in that regard?

Comment: The index notation looks like a dead end to me, because $(A_{ij})^{-1}\neq (A^{-1})_{ij}$. One has to find a way to introduce the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ rather than inverse of the matrix entries.

Comment: When you write \text{det} instead of \det, then you see $3\text{det} A$ instead of $3\det A.$ The spacing is context-dependent, so that the amount of space to the right of $\det$ in $3\det A$ is larger than that in $3\det(A).$ \text{} does not have that feature. With $\operatorname{tr} A$ I've used \operatorname{} in my edits to your question.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe This is a good observation, but it turns out that there *is* a way to introduce the inverse matrix in index notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the formula for the inverse matrix in index notation:
$$\left(A^{-1}\right)_{1i}=\frac{\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{j2}A_{k3}}{\det(A)}$$
and similarly with $1$, $2$ and $3$ cycled. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242539/matrix-inversion-via-levi-civita-symbols).

So
$$\varepsilon_{ijk} \left(\frac{d}{dt}(A_{i1})A_{j2}A_{k3}+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{j2})A_{i1}A_{k3}+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{k3})A_{i1}A_{j2})\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}(A_{i1})\left(A^{-1}\right)_{1i}\det(A)+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{j2})\left(A^{-1}\right)_{2j}\det(A)+\frac{d}{dt}(A_{k3})\left(A^{-1}\right)_{3k}\det(A)$$
$$=\det(A)\left(\left(A^{-1}\right)_{1i}\frac{d}{dt}(A_{i1})+\left(A^{-1}\right)_{2j}\frac{d}{dt}(A_{j2})+\left(A^{-1}\right)_{3k}\frac{d}{dt}(A_{k3})\right)$$
$$=\det(A)\left(\left(A^{-1}\right)_{li}\frac{d}{dt}(A_{il})\right)$$
$$=\det(A)\operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}\right)$$