# Matrix manipulations with Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, determinant, inverse, index-notation

My question relates to this [reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243411/413679) on math.stackexchange.

More precisely, I am wondering about the following sequence of expressions involving elements of an invertible square matrix $M$ and a pair of Levi-Civita symbols.

First, it is known that determinant $\det M$ can be expressed as
$$\det(M)=\tfrac 1{n!}\varepsilon^{i_1i_2\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{j_1j_2\dots j_n}M^{j_1}_{\quad i_1}M^{j_2}_{\quad i_2}\dots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n}.$$

Second, the formula for the adjugate matrix is very similar to the previous one:
$$\mathrm{adj}(M)^{a}_{\; {b}}=\tfrac 1{(n-1)!}\;\varepsilon^{ai_2\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{bj_2\dots j_n}M^{j_2}_{\quad i_2}\dots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n}$$
and it has a particularly neat interpretation in terms of the inverse $M^{-1}$ and of determinant $\det M$, namely
$$(M^{-1})^a_{\; b}=\frac{\mathrm{adj}(M)^a_{\; b}}{\det(M)}.$$
All of the above formulas can be found in various books on differential geometry.

It seems natural to me to construct a `next term' in sequence to the two above functions on $M$: one which further extends the formulas for $\det$ and $\mathrm{adj}$ as
$$\mathrm{fun}(M)^{a_1 a_2}_{\; \; \; \; b_1 b_2}=\tfrac 1{(n-2)!\times 2!}\;\varepsilon^{a_1 a_2 i_3\dots i_n}\varepsilon_{b_1 b_2 j_3\dots j_n}M^{j_3}_{\quad i_3}\dots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n},$$
which however does not seem to be considered in the differential geometry textbooks I checked.

I am trying to understand whether $\mathrm{fun}(M)^{a_1 a_2}_{\; \; \; \; b_1 b_2}$ as defined above can be related in some easy way to matrix inverse/power/determinant, in a spirit similar to the case of the adjugate matrix. My hunch is that two copies of $M^{-1}$ should somehow be involved, but I keep failing to connect the dots.

Comment: Nice question. We may have to clean up the factors in front of the $\varepsilon$s a bit but I think what happens is that $\operatorname{fun}(M)$ is a fourth order tensor that gives the determinant when contracted twice with $M$ and the adjugate when contracted only once. So, modulo factors, and in coordinate free notation:
$$
M^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{fun}(M)(M)}{\operatorname{fun}(M)(M,M)}\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this looks legit. Although this is not quite what I was hoping for, your comment helps me express more sharply what I am wondering about. Namely, the following multiplication of the adjugate of $M$ with a rank-1 vector results in a simple formula: $\textrm{adj}(M)^a_{\;b}v^b\sim (\det M)M^{-1}v$ in terms of an (inverse) power and determinant of $M$. Could there be a similar kind of formula in terms of powers & determinant of $M$ for the action $\textrm{fun}(M)^{ab}_{\;\;cd} X^{cd}$ on a rank-2 tensor? Perhaps sth where $X$ is multiplied by $M^{-1}$ in both indices $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Here a conjecture after playing Mathematica (checked for $m=1,2$, $n=3,4$). Let $\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1\ldots a_m}_{\qquad b_1\ldots b_m}=\frac{1}{(n-m)!m!}\epsilon^{a_1\ldots a_m i_{m+1}\ldots i_n}_{\qquad \qquad \quad b_1\ldots b_m j_{m+1}\ldots j_n}M^{j_{m+1}}_{\qquad i_{m+1}}\cdots M^{j_n}_{\quad i_n}$ be the $m$th adjugate of $M$. Then for $m$-form $X$ it holds that $\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1\ldots a_m}_{\qquad b_1\ldots b_m}X^{b_1\ldots b_m}=(\det M)(M^{-1})^{a_1}_{\;\;b_1}\cdots(M^{-1})^{a_m}_{\;\;b_m}X^{b_1\ldots b_m}$. But I fail to prove it generally. Could my conjecture be true?

Comment: Why not? It looks like you invented $\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1\ldots a_m}_{\qquad b_1\ldots b_m}$ to exactly fulfil that purpose.

Comment: Well, the conjectured relation was really not obvious to me! I simply followed the indices where they led me (in some application to a physics problem) and then became stuck at trying to simplify some very similar relation. But I believe I have now finally managed to connect the dots, and typed a proof in an answer below (I hope I didn't miss anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant pattern here is perhaps the following.

If the adjugate matrix is multiplied by a degree-1 tensor $\alpha$, one obtains (from the identity mentioned in the question) that
$$\textrm{adj}(M)^a_{\phantom{a}b} \alpha^b = (\det M) (M^{-1})^a_{\phantom{a}b} \alpha^b.$$
Similarly, multiplication of $\textrm{fun}(M)^{a_1 a_2}_{\phantom{a_1 a_2}b_1 b_2}$ by a degree-2 skew-symmetric tensor $\beta$ results in
$$\textrm{fun}(M)^{a_1 a_2}_{\phantom{a_1 a_2} b_1 b_2} \beta^{b_1 b_2} = (\det M) (M^{-1})^{a_1}_{\phantom{a_1}b_1} (M^{-1})^{a_2}_{\phantom{a_2}b_2} \beta^{b_1b_2}.$$
More generally, let
$$\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1 \cdots a_m}_{\phantom{a_1 \cdots a_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} = \frac{1}{(n-m)!\times m!}\epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_m i_{m+1}\cdots i_n}\epsilon_{b_1 \cdots b_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n}M^{j_{m+1}}_{\phantom{j_{m+1}}{i_{m+1}}}\cdots M^{j_n}_{\phantom{j_n}i_n}.\qquad(1)$$
One might perhaps call $\textrm{adj}_m(M)$ the "order-$m$ adjugate matrix of $M$" (although perhaps another accepted name could be found in the literature). It can be shown that
for a degree-$m$ fully skew-symmetric tensor $\gamma$
$$\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1 \cdots a_m}_{\phantom{a_1 \cdots a_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} \gamma^{b_{1}\cdots b_m} = (\det M) (M^{-1})^{a_1}_{\phantom{a_1}b_1} \cdots (M^{-1})^{a_m}_{\phantom{a_m}b_m} \gamma^{b_1 \cdots b_m}.$$

**Proof**

In the proof I will refer to some results that are either shown or left as an exercise in the [book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511755590) *Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists* by  Fecko. To start, multiply equation (1) by $M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m}$ to get
$$M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m} \textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1 \cdots a_m}_{\phantom{a_1 \cdots a_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} = \frac{1}{(n-m)!\times m!}\epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_m i_{m+1}\cdots i_n}\epsilon_{b_1 \cdots b_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n}M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m}M^{j_{m+1}}_{\phantom{j_{m+1}}{i_{m+1}}}\cdots M^{j_n}_{\phantom{j_n}i_n}\qquad(2).$$
Observe that on the right-hand side the $n$ superscripts of the first Levi-Civita symbol match precisely the subscripts of the $n$ matrices $M$. We use that
$$\epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_m i_{m+1}\cdots i_n} M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m}M^{j_{m+1}}_{\phantom{j_{m+1}}{i_{m+1}}}\cdots M^{j_n}_{\phantom{j_n}i_n} = (\det M) \epsilon^{c_1 \cdots c_m j_{m+1} \cdots j_n}$$
(this is essentially contained in exercise $\boxed{5.6.5}$ of the book by  Fecko). Therefore, equation (2) is rewritten to
$$M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m} \textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1 \cdots a_m}_{\phantom{a_1 \cdots a_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!\times m!}\delta^{c_1 \cdots c_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n}_{b_1 \cdots b_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n}(\det M).\qquad (3)$$
where we utilized the generalized Kronecker symbol
$$\delta^{a_1\cdots a_n}_{b_1 \cdots b_n} = \frac{1}{n!} \epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_n}\epsilon_{b_1 \cdots b_n}.$$
Note that $(n-m)$ indices of the generalized Kronecker symbol are contracted in equation (3), so we use
$$\delta^{c_1 \cdots c_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n}_{b_1 \cdots b_m j_{m+1}\cdots j_n} = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \delta^{c_1 \cdots c_m}_{b_1 \cdots b_m}$$
(exercise $\boxed{5.6.4}$ in Fecko's book). With this, equation (3) simplifies to
$$M^{c_1}_{\phantom{c_1}a_1}\cdots M^{c_m}_{\phantom{c_m}a_m} \textrm{adj}_m(M)^{a_1 \cdots a_m}_{\phantom{a_1 \cdots a_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} = \delta^{c_1 \cdots c_m}_{b_1 \cdots b_m}(\det M).$$
From here, multiplication with $\gamma^{b_1 \cdots b_m} (M^{-1})^{d_1}_{\phantom{d_1}c_1}\cdots (M^{-1})^{d_m}_{\phantom{d_m}c_m}$ and some basic manipulation with Kronecker deltas trivially gives
$$\textrm{adj}_m(M)^{d_1 \cdots d_m}_{\phantom{d_1 \cdots d_m}{b_1 \cdots b_m}} \gamma^{b_{1}\cdots b_m} = (\det M) (M^{-1})^{d_1}_{\phantom{d_1}c_1} \cdots (M^{-1})^{d_m}_{\phantom{d_m}c_m} \gamma^{c_1 \cdots c_m}$$
which (up to some renamed indices) is the identity we set out to prove.